# Simple table formatting

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

I am trying to format the below code so that the table looks as follows:

[image]

I have tried adding toprule and midrule, but I couldn't achieve my goal. Here is the code I have so far.

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} 

\hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
\hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
X & 0.198*** & 0.216*** & 0.141*** & 0.324*** & 0.305*** & 0.189*** \\
 & (0.0472) & (0.0399) & (0.0394) & (0.0456) & (0.0407) & (0.0374) \\
X2 & 0.153** & 0.281*** & 0.282*** & 0.353*** & 0.518*** & 0.448*** \\
 & (0.0632) & (0.0627) & (0.0592) & (0.0854) & (0.0834) & (0.0718) \\
X3 & 0.0577 & -0.0426 & -0.0985* & 0.0102 & -0.133* & -0.158** \\
 & (0.0555) & (0.0519) & (0.0508) & (0.0715) & (0.0693) & (0.0628) \\
Number of Nonstop Carriers &  &  & -0.0105*** &  &  & -0.00816** \\
 &  &  & (0.00262) &  &  & (0.00350) \\
Bus Indicator &  &  & -0.118*** &  &  & -0.148*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00936) &  &  & (0.0137) \\
Other PMS Indicator &  &  & -0.0589*** &  &  & -0.0982*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00743) &  &  & (0.0101) \\
Share of Passengers Traveling Connect, City-Level &  &  & 0.129*** &  &  & 0.177*** \\
 &  &  & (0.0173) &  &  & (0.0192) \\
Share of Passengers Traveling Connect &  &  & 0.104*** &  &  & 0 \\
 &  &  & (0.0139) &  &  & (5.35e-09) \\
Log(Population) &  &  & 0.304*** &  &  & 0.341*** \\
 &  &  & (0.106) &  &  & (0.122) \\
Log(Income Per Capita) &  &  & 0.373*** &  &  & 0.318*** \\
 &  &  & (0.102) &  &  & (0.109) \\
Constant & 5.043*** & 6.100*** & 5.545*** & 4.936*** & 0.636 & 2.836*** \\
 & (0.0203) & (0.249) & (0.447) & (0.0279) & (0.586) & (0.669) \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 1,237,878 & 1,237,878 & 1,209,791 & 262,534 & 262,534 & 255,173 \\
R-squared & 0.821 & 0.826 & 0.836 & 0.852 & 0.861 & 0.876 \\
Number of city-state pairs & 46510 & 46510 & 45244 &  &  &  \\
 Number of cities &  &  &  & 7190 & 7190 & 6911 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your question is not just about the partial horizontal lines  but also about adding the two additional column header rows, I'd suggest the following: In the example, I have used `booktabs` for lines with a bit more vertical white space around them. Since the table will be too tall for a landscape page if we use these lines and add two more rows, I have removed the `landscape` environment. To make the table fit into the textwidth I have added linebreaks in the longer contents of the first column and also lightly decreased the font size. To provide a guide to the eye, I have added some vertical white space between the entries:

[image]

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
\noindent{\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccccc@{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Y}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City-State Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State-Level}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
\midrule
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
X & 0.198*** & 0.216*** & 0.141*** & 0.324*** & 0.305*** & 0.189*** \\
 & (0.0472) & (0.0399) & (0.0394) & (0.0456) & (0.0407) & (0.0374) \\ \addlinespace
X2 & 0.153** & 0.281*** & 0.282*** & 0.353*** & 0.518*** & 0.448*** \\
 & (0.0632) & (0.0627) & (0.0592) & (0.0854) & (0.0834) & (0.0718) \\ \addlinespace
X3 & 0.0577 & -0.0426 & -0.0985* & 0.0102 & -0.133* & -0.158** \\
 & (0.0555) & (0.0519) & (0.0508) & (0.0715) & (0.0693) & (0.0628) \\ \addlinespace
Number of Nonstop  &  &  & -0.0105*** &  &  & -0.00816** \\
Carriers &  &  & (0.00262) &  &  & (0.00350) \\ \addlinespace
Bus Indicator &  &  & -0.118*** &  &  & -0.148*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00936) &  &  & (0.0137) \\ \addlinespace
Other PMS Indicator &  &  & -0.0589*** &  &  & -0.0982*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00743) &  &  & (0.0101) \\ \addlinespace
Share of Passengers Traveling  &  &  & 0.129*** &  &  & 0.177*** \\
Connect, City-Level &  &  & (0.0173) &  &  & (0.0192) \\ \addlinespace
Share of Passengers Traveling  &  &  & 0.104*** &  &  & 0 \\
Connect &  &  & (0.0139) &  &  & (5.35e-09) \\ \addlinespace
Log(Population) &  &  & 0.304*** &  &  & 0.341*** \\
 &  &  & (0.106) &  &  & (0.122) \\ \addlinespace
Log(Income Per Capita) &  &  & 0.373*** &  &  & 0.318*** \\
 &  &  & (0.102) &  &  & (0.109) \\ \addlinespace
Constant & 5.043*** & 6.100*** & 5.545*** & 4.936*** & 0.636 & 2.836*** \\
 & (0.0203) & (0.249) & (0.447) & (0.0279) & (0.586) & (0.669) \\ \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 1,237,878 & 1,237,878 & 1,209,791 & 262,534 & 262,534 & 255,173 \\
R-squared & 0.821 & 0.826 & 0.836 & 0.852 & 0.861 & 0.876 \\
Number of city-state pairs & 46510 & 46510 & 45244 &  &  &  \\
 Number of cities &  &  &  & 7190 & 7190 & 6911 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}}

%\end{landscape}




\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much. Works very well!

Answer (score 2):

`booktabs` package for partial rules:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{"Dependent Variable: Log(Average Fare)"} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
\addlinespace
X & 0.198*** & 0.216*** & 0.141*** & 0.324*** & 0.305*** & 0.189*** \\
 & (0.0472) & (0.0399) & (0.0394) & (0.0456) & (0.0407) & (0.0374) \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your answer is extremely helpful. I have just one followup question. When the "Dependent Variable" part is long, it doesn't fit into the middle. In other words, then I have "Dependent Variable: Log(Average Fare)", the top parts doesn't enline anymore. Any questions?

Comment: @Job I don't understand "doesn't enline anymore". Can you please rephrase?

Comment: For some reason the first column title "Dependent Variable: Log(Average Fare)" was staying on the left side (i.e., not centering). But the code below somehow overcomes this (i.e., when I use the entire data, this issue doesn't appear). Your answer was very helpful!!! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Job Nice to hear it was helpful!